# Almacenar un valor null en SQL Server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2019

Estoy haciendo un programa en Visual Studio 2019 en el que puedo guardar y borrar documentos de una base de datos. Para borrar uso este código:

```
string actualizar = "UPDATE tabla SET documento = @documento WHERE p = @p AND n = @n;";
SqlCommand borrar = new SqlCommand(actualizar, con);
borrar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", p);
borrar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", n);
borrar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", null ?? DBNull.Value);

con.Open();
borrar.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

El problema es que salta el siguiente error y creo que es por darle un valor null a "documento". Igualmente no sé como puedo usar `CONVERT` con null:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'No se permite la conversión implícita del tipo de datos nvarchar a varbinary(max). Utilice la función CONVERT para ejecutar esta consulta.'

He intentado `borrar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", null);`, pero salta este error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'La consulta con parámetros '(@p nvarchar(7),@n nvarchar(4),@documento' espera el parámetro '@documento', que no se ha proporcionado.'

Comment: Prueba directamente metiendo DBNull ..  ("@documento", DBNull.Value);

Comment: @LucianoMontañez de esa forma también me daba error, pero ya he conseguido solucionarlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya he conseguido que funcione. Simplemente tenía que sustituir esta sentencia `borrar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", null ?? DBNull.Value);` por esta otra `borrar.Parameters.Add("@documento", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;`